# Is every $\sigma$-algebra also a semi-ring?

Tags: measure-theory

I wanted to know if every sigma algebra is a semi-ring? Looks like to me it is implied by the definition of a semi-ring. However I read many books and none of the books state that it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on the second slide of page 2 on [this PDF file](http://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/sR-0.pdf),

> "All σ-algebras are algebras, and all algebras are semi-rings."

Comment: Thanks abunch. That was helpful.